# RESTful: how to send data through PUT and DELETE

Tags: php, rest

I decided I will start using RESTful URLs in the name of good practice. However, as always, it has not been long before the struggle began.

So from what I understand I should use `PUT` to update, however there is no `$_PUT` superglobal in PHP. So this led to a highly scientific experiment consisting of creating a form with method `PUT` with the intention to find out how `PUT` data is sent. I was surprised to discover `GET` parameters in the URL.

There must be something that I'm missing, because there is just no way I can ever use data from the URL to update a database or something. What if I require the user to input their password in order to update their settings? This is unspeakable. Can anyone please shed some light on me?

Comment: There is no `PUT` superglobal in PHP. You can use `$_POST` to send data

Comment: `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') { parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$post_vars); }` Use cURL for sending requests.

Comment: the content of `php://input` is `string(0) ""`

Comment: @hex494D49 OP's specifically asked to use `RESTful` instead of `cURL`

Comment: @BasitSaeed but if I send update data through `$_POST` that is breaking the idea of RESTful?

Comment: You can send the request method as `PUT` via headers. On your server-side, you can check the request method simply via 
`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT'){
    parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $post_vars);
}`

Comment: @BasitSaeed but, as I already said, `php://input` is empty

Comment: In fact now I noticed that even though my form method is `PUT` in my net tab on firebug I see the request method is `GET`, what the?

Comment: You have to put your form method as `POST`. `PUT` is something you handle on your own, not a standard method to transfer data.

Comment: @BasitSaeed I'm afraid you're mixing things. You may use `cURL` and still have `RESTful URL`

Comment: @BasitSaeed from what I learned the four methods are standard and furthermore REST makes no sense without either one of them

Comment: @MoshMage have you even read the question? How is that a duplicate of detecting the request type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought, I was able to send PUT and DELETE request from an HTML form but it didn't result in a PUT, but in a GET request.

In order to have RESTful URLs using HTML form, I would use POST requst and something like this

```
// JavaScript
window.onload = function(){

    var f = document.getElementById('form');
    f.button.onclick = function(){
        var username = f.username.value;
        var password = f.password.value;
        // in a final application I would use a form serializer

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://www.domain.com/restful/";
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { 
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);

                // you may return a JSON as well
                // var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                // console.log(json.username);
            }
        }
        var data = JSON.stringify({"username":"" + username + "","password":"" + password + ""});
        xhr.send(data);

    }
}

<!-- HTML form -->
<form id="form" method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Submit" />
</form>

// PHP
header("Content-Type: application/json");
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $input = json_decode(stripslashes(file_get_contents("php://input")), true);
    echo $input['username'];

    // in case you return a JSON, encode data first
    // echo json_encode($input);
}
```

The `.htaccess` remains the same

---

[Initial answer]

This way you could build your `PUT` request

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/restful/';
$data = array('username'=>'hey@mail.com','password'=>'101010');
$data_json = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

Or `DELETE` request, like this

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This is the index.php file within `restful` directory

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
    $input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); 
    echo $input->username;
}elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'DELETE'){
    // ...
}
```

You may use `.htaccess` within `resful` direcotry to redirect everything  to index.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: But the question is how to send `PUT` or `DELETE` from a browser form, which is practically impossible, but still, how do sites that use RESTful URLs do it?

Comment: @php_nub_qq I updated my answer so give it a try; and sorry for bothering :)